# Get-Module -ListAvailable doesn't display my module

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I've created a module manifest `.psd1` file and I've used `Test-ModuleManifest` on it which returns nicely and shows the two CmdLets in the binary C# .dll.

The manifest file is in a folder under `c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` but when I run `Get-Module -ListAvailable` it is not showing.

If I run `Get-Module` it is not showing.

If I run one of the CmdLets then the module is automatically imported and shows when I next run `Get-Module`.

What am I misunderstanding?? Why doesn't it show as available?

Update

Just done this again with a script module, `psm1` and `psd1` on a different machine, and same problem. It doesn't show as available and yet `posh-git` which seems to be setup in a similar way, does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the script module *does* now show up after I fixed a version inconsistency between the version in the manifest and the subfolder name I'd placed it in.

Came in handy:

```
Test-ModuleManifest
```